# devenv.exe /upgrade not working as intended

Tags: visual-studio, devenv

I am trying to use devenv.exe to upgrade Visual Studio 2013 solution files through the command line.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" TimeReportingDataMart.sln /Upgrade`

But there is no output, and the solution does not upgrade. Is devenv not the correct tool for this? Or am I just missing something completely?

Comment: There is devenv.exe and devenv.com.  The latter was designed for command line usage and what you get when you type "devenv jadajada".  But there's little point, it is an IDE so just use File > Open and if an upgrade is *necessary* then it happens automagically.  It rarely is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was calling `devenv.exe` when I should have been calling `devenv`.

Calling,
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" TimeReportingDataMart.sln /Upgrade` fails.

But calling

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv" TimeReportingDataMart.sln /Upgrade` gives me output.

It gives:

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.

Information:
This project/solution does not require migration. It will open without modification.
```

Which doesn't help me, but at least I got the command to run..